# Insert $\operatorname{cov}(X_1, X_2)$ into equation

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, mathematical-modeling, variance, descriptive-statistics

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$I'm currently trying to solve/complete a statistics project. So far, I have finished the first part of the project. However, one of the tasks in the second part is causing me trouble.

I'm given a random variable, let's call it $C_1$, which describes a portfolio consisting of $1$ and $2$.

$C_1$ is defined as as the following: $C_1 = \alpha X_1 + (1 – \alpha) X_2$.

I then had to define an expression for the variance of $C_1$, i.e. $\Var(C_1)$. Considering the definition of $C1$, that means I had to define an expression for $\Var(α X_1 + (1 – α) X_2)$.

So according to my book, I ended up with the following:

$$\Var(C1) = \Var(α X_1 + (1 – α) X_2) = α^2 \Var(X_1) + (1 – α)^2 \Var(X_2).$$

I don't know if my expression is correct, but that is how I think it should be according to the book.

Now, my task is to express $\Var(C_1$) as a function of $α$, more specifically $V(α)$. I'm pretty sure $V$ is just an abbreviation for variance. So I set up the following:

$$V(α) = α^2 \Var(X_1) + (1 – α)^2 \Var(X_2).$$

Now, according to the project, I have to insert the values for $\Var(X_1), \Var(X_2)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1, X_2)$ into the equation. I have calculated these values in the first part of the project and it was pretty easy to insert the values for $\Var(X_1)$ and $\Var(X_2)$ into the equation. However, I can't figure out what is meant by inserting the covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$ into it. I have calculated the covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$, but don't know where to insert it into the equation. I have been looking at this for days now and re-read a lot of the pages in my book, but I'm stuck.

I know you haven't seen the project tasks, but maybe someone could point out what's going wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{var}(\alpha X_1 + (1-\alpha)X_2) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{var}(\alpha X_1) + \operatorname{var}((1-\alpha)X_2) + 2\operatorname{cov}(\alpha X_1, (1-\alpha)X_2) \\[10pt]
= {} & \alpha^2 \operatorname{var}(X_1) + (1-\alpha)^2 \operatorname{var}(X_2) + 2\alpha(1-\alpha)\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2).
\end{align}

You don't need the last term if the covariance is $0$, and that happens if (but not only if) the two random variables being added are independent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The covariance is approximately 0.0010. So that means I was missing the last part, i.e. 2α(1−α)cov(X1,X2) in my equation since the covariance is not 0? So what I read in the book must have been for cases where the random variables are independent. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @A.Jakobsen : That is correct. Although the covariance is $0$ also in some cases where the two random variables are not independent.